# Get title displayed instead of URL

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How can I get a title displayed for an URL instead of `HTTP://localhost:8000/home/6/`?

My URL is

```
path('', views.homepage, name='home'),
path('<int:services_id>/', views.details, name='details'),
path('<int:prgmm_id>/program/', views.program, name='program')
```

Answer (score 0):

create a slug field in your model and slugify the title, an example is shown below for ref:

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
        return super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and change the url to

```
path('program/<slug:slug>/', views.program, name='program')
```

Comment: so what about the id in the URL path

Comment: instead of id the individual instances will be available by the title(slugified title) which will be unique, for ref:https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/slugfield.html

Comment: i tried that and i got some errors again ' class prgm(models.Model):
    

     image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='image1')
     image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='image2')
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, default='title')' -------------------------------and my URL is -------------------------------------  path('details/<slug:slug>/', views.details, name='details'),---------and html url path is----------- <a href="{% url 'details' services.id %}">-------------------and my error is---program() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'

Comment: Should not add a default for slug field as it should vary on each instance(unique)